# Why is the result of MMA polynomial mod factor different from that of this article?

Tags: polynomials, factorization

Why the polynomial mod factor of MMA is not the same as the result of [this SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322623):

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := x^6 - 8 x^4 - 5 x^3 + 4 x^2 + 5 x - 12
Factor[PolynomialMod[f[x], 3]]
Factor[f[x], Modulus -> 3]
Out[1]= x (x+1) (x^4-x^3+2 x^2-x+2)
        x (x+1) (x+2) (x^3+2 x+1)
```

The results in that answer are:

> *Consider the polynomial
>   $$
> f(x)=x^6-8x^4-5x^3+4x^2+5x-12.
> $$
>   Modulo $p=3$ it factors as $f(x)\equiv (x^3-x)(x^3-x+1)=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^3-x+1)$ so the Galois group has a 3-cycle.*

Comment: The factorization $\bmod 3$ is the same because $2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.